# consuming wcf on real android device not emulator

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I  have client /server  application. server is written in c# and client is android 2.2. 
I am using JSON http service to connect client with server. Server is running on local machine.

I have tested my application it works well when I run it in emulator. Now I wanted to run it on Android real device. I have installed the client app on android phone. As wcf needs internet permission so I enabled the wifi(Wifi is running fine) on android phone, but my app is not connecting with server.

How can I connect client with server?
whether I need to make any changing in ip address or what else?
Thanks everyone for help

Comment: My first guess would be the firewall or router on you server not allowing the outside connection

Comment: @sa_ddam213, you mean network permission on router? and how to check both to permit?